# Algorithm - iteration method

Tags: algorithms

> $$\begin{align} &T(n)=n+T(n-1)= \\ 
> &= n + (n-1)+T(n-2)= \\ 
> &= n + (n-1)+(n-2)+T(n-3)= \\ 
> &= n + (n-1)+(n-2)+...+2+T(1)= \\
> &= \frac{n(n+1)}{2}-1+T(1) \\
> & \mathrm{Hence,} \ T(n)=\frac{n^2+n}{2}-1+T(1)=\Theta(n^2) 
> \end{align} $$

What is $n(n+1)$?

Comment: Can you explain what is $\theta(n^2)$?

Answer (score 0):

$T(n) = n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 2 + T(1)$
$\quad\quad\; = n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 2 + 1 - 1 + T(1)$
$\quad\quad\; = (\sum_{i=1}^{n} i ) - 1 + T(1)$
$\quad\quad\; = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} - 1 + T(1)$

Comment: He already have written it, how does your post help? and an advice - use \displaystyle command in your LaTeX code.

Comment: @Galc127 I believe the OP was asking where the n(n+1)/2 came from. The $\Theta(n^2)$ is an asymptotic notation.

Comment: he have written it as \theta instead of \Theta and it wasn't clear to me. I edited the post again and we shall wait to the OP to clarify.